# 1 row for all product gallery images

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to make the product gallery show all images on only 1 row. 
Currently it is displaying 2 rows. 3 images on the first row and 1 image on the second row. Please take a look at the [page](http://goo.gl/L3IswC).

I tried this code but it didn't really help:

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 'xx_thumb_cols' );
 function xx_thumb_cols() {
     return 1; // .last class applied to every 4th thumbnail
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted only changes where the `last` class is applied. You should `return 4` so that the 4th item gets the `last` class. However, you also need to adjust the CSS

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce-page div.product div.thumbnails a {
  float: left;
  width: 30.75%;
  margin-right: 3.8%;
}
```

needs to be modified to:

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.thumbnails a, .woocommerce-page div.product div.thumbnails a {
  float: left;
  width: 22.1%;
  margin-right: 3.8%;
}
```

If you don't shrink the width, the items will never all fit on the single line.